# BeginWaitForConnection and Generic.List concurrency

Tags: c#, asynchronous, concurrency

I'm using a `NamedPipeServerStream` and `BeginWaitForConnection` that gets called for every client connecting to the stream. The callback it takes manipulates a shared static `List`.
I'm wondering if the fact that `BeginWaitForConnection` is asynchronous and may be running multiple callbacks in parallel will raise a concurrency issue for that `List`. I've tried running it a few times and it seems to have worked ok, but I'm not sure if it's thread-safe. Should I be using `ConcurrentBag` instead, or `lock(files) {...}` around my `FetchFile` code? I'm no stranger to asynchronous concepts and multi-threading, but concurrency is fairly new to me, so any insight here is much appreciated.

`PipeListener` is the entry point here.

```
static List<string> files = new List<string>();

static void PipeListener()
{
    NamedPipeServerStream server = new NamedPipeServerStream("MyPipe", PipeDirection.In, -1,
                                   PipeTransmissionMode.Byte, PipeOptions.Asynchronous);
    server.BeginWaitForConnection(FetchFile, server);
}

static void FetchFile(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    PipeListener();
    NamedPipeServerStream server = ar.AsyncState as NamedPipeServerStream;
    server.EndWaitForConnection(ar);
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(server);
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        files.Add(reader.ReadLine());
    server.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the callback for `BeginWaitForConnection` you already start a new `BeginWaitForConnection` call. This means that concurrent invocations are possible and you need to protect shared state.

Note, that you probably should use `await` instead of the obsolete APM. Also don't forget to manage your resources with `using`.

Comment: So how should I protect shared state? And doesn't `BeginWaitForConnection` already abstract the asynchronization? Unless you're suggesting I switch to the synchronous version and handle the async myself? I don't really follow. It's just a barebones feasibility study for now so not too concerned with the resources, but good catch.

Comment: You can have two concurrent FetchFile calls so any resources touched by FetchFile must be accessed in a safe way. lock seems fine here.

Comment: Using the synchronous version is even better because the code becomes simpler and it does not look like you will be dealing with dozens of concurrent connections. But you need to start each connection on a new Task/Thread so this does not save you from the concurrency issues.

Comment: Lock it is. Cheers!